# PHP Form won't let me add a New Row to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to add in a new row to a MySQL table. It is reading me the error `Could not enter data: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` . So far, I am using the code

```
if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
   $job_pos = addslashes ($_POST['job_pos']);
}
else
{
   $job_pos = $_POST['job_pos'];
}
$job_pos_sort = "SELECT LAST(job_pos_sort) FROM careers;" + 1;

$sql = "INSERT INTO careers ".
       "(job_pos, job_pos_sort) ".
       "VALUES('$job_pos', '$job_pos_sort', NOW())";
```

to insert a new row into the table.

Here is my entire code for the page, my page can be seen at http://thetotempole.ca/phptester/upanddowntest.php :

```
<?php
// connect to db
$conn = mysql_connect("xxxx","x","x","x") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('x',$conn) or die(mysql_error());

// if an arrow link was clicked...
if ($_GET['dir'] && $_GET['id']) {
   // make GET vars easier to handle
   $dir = $_GET['dir'];
   // cast as int and couple with switch for sql injection prevention for $id
   $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
   // decide what row we're swapping based on $dir
   switch ($dir) {
      // if we're going up, swap is 1 less than id
      case 'up': 
         // make sure that there's a row above to swap
         $swap = ($id > 1)? $id-- : 1;
         break;
      // if we're going down, swap is 1 more than id
      case 'down':
         // find out what the highest row is
         $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM careers";
         $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
         $r = mysql_fetch_row($result);
         $max = $r[0];
         // make sure that there's a row below to swap with
         $swap = ($id < $max)? $id++ : $max;
         break;
      // default value (sql injection prevention for $dir)
      default:
         $swap = $id;
   } // end switch $dir
   // swap the rows. Basic idea is to make $id=$swap and $swap=$id 
   $sql = "UPDATE careers SET job_pos_sort = CASE job_pos_sort WHEN $id THEN $swap WHEN $swap THEN $id END WHERE job_pos_sort IN ($id, $swap)";
   $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
} // end if GET  

// set a result order with a default (sql infection prevention for $sortby)
$sortby = ($_GET['sortby'] == 'job_pos')? $_GET['sortby'] : 'job_pos_sort';
// pull the info from the table
$sql = "SELECT job_pos_sort, job_pos FROM careers ORDER BY $sortby";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

// display table
echo "<table border = '1'>";
echo "<tr>";
// make column names links, passing sortby
echo "<td><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sortby=job_pos_sort'>job_pos_sort</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sortby=job_pos'>job_pos</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
// display data 1 row at a time
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo "<tr>";
   // make the links to change custom order, passing direction and the custom sort id
   echo "<td align = 'center'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?dir=up&id={$r['job_pos_sort']}'>/\</a> ";
   echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?dir=down&id={$r['job_pos_sort']}'>\/</a></td>";
   echo "<td>{$r['job_pos']}</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
} // end while $r
echo "</table>";
// end display table
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Manage Careers</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$dbhost = 'x';
$dbuser = 'xx';
$dbpass = 'xx';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
   $job_pos = addslashes ($_POST['job_pos']);
}
else
{
   $job_pos = $_POST['job_pos'];
}
$job_pos_sort = "SELECT LAST(job_pos_sort) FROM careers;" + 1;

$sql = "INSERT INTO careers ".
       "(job_pos, job_pos_sort) ".
       "VALUES('$job_pos', '$job_pos_sort', NOW())";
mysql_select_db('x');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Job Position</td>
<td><input name="job_pos" type="text" id="job_pos"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Add Job Position">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Kelsey

Comment: why don't you use auto_increment on job_pos_sort, and there is nothing called LAST in mysql it is MAX, additionally as the answer below you are inserting 3 values in 2 columns, and your $job_post_sort will be inserted as string into the database

Comment: I tried auto increment and it gave me an error when trying to move a row up or down. I did manage to get it fixed thanks to Royal Bg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are expecting to happen when specifying 2 columns, and trying to add 3

```
   "INSERT INTO careers ".
   "(job_pos, job_pos_sort) ".
   "VALUES('$job_pos', '$job_pos_sort', NOW())
```

Googling the error would help you. It exactly tells what you are getting wrong.

columns `job_pos`, `job_pos_sort`, but values - `job_pos`, `job_post_sort` and `NOW()`. You might have to specify the last column, which seems to be a datetime one

I hope you also are aware the $job_pos_sort is just a string, and want evaluate to anything, especially with adding 1 to the string (it may rise an error too)

And, you'd better switch to one of the modern DB API's regarding mysql - mysqli or PDO.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 0):

you should run this :

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM careers;
```

then maybe we know the name of the field missing here xxxxxx
it must be a sort of date.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO careers ".
       "(job_pos, job_pos_sort, xxxxxx) ".
       "VALUES('$job_pos', '$job_pos_sort', NOW())";
```

or simply try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO careers ".
       "(job_pos, job_pos_sort) ".
       "VALUES('$job_pos', '$job_pos_sort')";
```

this should work